# (Python) Assignment to a column of a matrix returns all zero's

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am new to Python and NumPy, and was trying to make a matrix class with mean normalization and feature scaling. When I run a simple example normalization returns a column of all zero's. I tried looking for it, but found only `copy()` thingy, which is not really applicable. The code is below, any suggestions?

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

class NormMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self, X=[]):
        self.X = X
        self.normalized = False
        self._calcColumnVars()

    def _calcColumnVars(self):         # This thing gets the means and stuff
        self.mean = np.array([])
        self.minimum = np.array([])
        self.maximum = np.array([])
        for ii in range(0, len(self.X[0])):
            self.mean = np.append(self.mean, np.mean(self.X[:,ii]))
            self.minimum = np.append(self.minimum, np.min(self.X[:,ii]))
            self.maximum = np.append(self.maximum, np.max(self.X[:,ii]))

    def normalize(self):       # Offset by mean and normalize to range
        for ii in range(0, len(self.X[0])):
            if self.minimum[ii] == self.maximum[ii]:
                continue        # The column is all the same elements
            self.X[:,ii] = (self.X[:,ii] - self.mean[ii]) / (self.maximum[ii] - self.minimum[ii])
        self.normalized = True

    def show(self):
        print "X = %s"%np.array_str(self.X);
        print "Mean = %s"%np.array_str(self.mean, precision=2);
        print "Min = %s"%np.array_str(self.minimum, precision=2);
        print "Max = %s"%np.array_str(self.maximum, precision=2);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X = NormMatrix(np.array([[1,1,1,1], [89,72,94,69], [1,2,3,4]]).transpose())
    X.show()
    X.normalize()
    X.show()
```

My output:

```
X = [[ 1 89  1]
 [ 1 72  2]
 [ 1 94  3]
 [ 1 69  4]]
Mean = [  1.   81.    2.5]
Min = [  1.  69.   1.]
Max = [  1.  94.   4.]
X = [[1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
Mean = [  1.   81.    2.5]
Min = [  1.  69.   1.]
Max = [  1.  94.   4.]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the array has an integer dtype, division returns integers:

```
In [5]: X = np.array([[1,1,1,1], [89,72,94,69], [1,2,3,4]])

In [7]: X.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('int64')

In [6]: X / 100
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

In contrast, if the array has a float dtype, then division returns floats:

```
In [8]: X = np.array([[1,1,1,1], [89,72,94,69], [1,2,3,4]])

In [9]: X = X.astype(float)

In [11]: X.dtype
Out[11]: dtype('float64')

In [10]: X / 100
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01],
       [ 0.89,  0.72,  0.94,  0.69],
       [ 0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04]])
```

---

Your code could be fixed by changing

```
    self.X = X
```

in `NormMatrix.__init__` to:

```
    self.X = np.asarray(X, dtype=float)
```

---

Also, you can take better advantage of NumPy by removing the `for-loops` and instead using the NumPy `mean`, `min`, `max` methods. The `axis=0` parameter tells these methods to take the `mean` (or `min` or `max`) over the rows. The result is an array with one value for each column. Specifying `axis=0` thus removes the 0-axis:

```
def _calcColumnVars(self):         # This thing gets the means and stuff
    self.mean = self.X.mean(axis=0)
    self.minimum = self.X.min(axis=0)
    self.maximum = self.X.max(axis=0)
```

and by using [NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to perform the normalization arithmetic:

```
def normalize(self):       # Offset by mean and normalize to range
    normed = (self.X - self.mean) / (self.maximum - self.minimum)
    self.X = np.where(np.isnan(normed), self.X, normed)
    self.normalized = True
```

Comment: OMG, I am so stupid!!! Spent the whole day working on it, and didn't even notice that!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: If I use NumPy broadcasting, is there a way to check if (max-min) returns a 0? If there is no way, then I cannot use it :(

Comment: If X is an array with float dtype, then division by zero returns `nan`. To preserve the value of `X` in that case, you *could* use `np.isnan` to identify those locations, and use `np.where` to return an array filled with values from `self.X` where `np.isnan(X)` is True, and from `normed` otherwise. (See the code. above.) This will be faster than using a `for-loop` *when the arrays have a lot of columns*. If the arrays are small, the `for-loop` may be faster.

Comment: Correction, in the broadcasting part of the answer - it should be "self.X = np.where(np.isnan(normed), self.X, normed)"